# Delphi XE6: How to load resource into TMemIniFile?

Tags: delphi, ini

I've been running Delphi XE6 and am trying to put read-only INI files into the EXE file.

That I have already solved. Also loading the files is working fine into TMemo.

I have defined the following function loading the pure TXT INI file from resource into TMemo:

```delphi
procedure LoadTXTfromResource(const ResourceName: string; OutMemo: TMemo);

var
  ResourceStream: TResourceStream;

begin
  ResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResourceName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    OutMemo.Lines.LoadFromStream(ResourceStream);
  finally
    ResourceStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It is working flawlessly.

Now, what I need, is to re-write the procedure to load the aforementioned text file into TMemIniFile.

---

I've been trying various things, but I can't seem to be able to do that. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the resource stream into a string list, and then transfer to the `TMemIniFile`.

```
procedure LoadINIfromResource(const ResourceName: string; IniFile: TMemIniFile);
var
  ResourceStream: TResourceStream;
  Text: TStringList;
begin
  ResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResourceName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Text := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Text.LoadFromStream(ResourceStream);
      IniFile.SetStrings(Text);
    finally
      Text.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ResourceStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that because your `TMemIniFile` is not file based, you must pass an empty string as the file name when instantiating it:

```
IniFile := TMemIniFile.Create('');
```